# Non-abelian group which squares to equal the identity element?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Does there exist a non-abelian group $G=\{e,g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}$ with order $n+1$ s.t.
\begin{align}
(g_1 \dots g_n)^2 = e
\end{align}

Also, does this change if we say that every element in $G$ is its own inverse?

Comment: Don't the quaternions and octonions (and other Clifford algebras) do this?

Comment: Also $S_3$ will do.

Comment: @ziggurism what do you mean? I don't see the connection of those algebras with this problem.

Comment: @rschwieb: I was thinking not the algebra of quaternions, but what's called the quaternion group: ±1,±i,±j, and ±k. ijk=-1, which squares to 1. Can also include -1,-i,-j,-k.  I was also thinking this was a special case of a more general for any Clifford algebra whose degree 1 elements are spanned by $\gamma_i$, then the product $\gamma_1\cdot\dotsb\cdot\gamma_n$, which also satisfies the required identity. But these elements do not form a group I think, so my suggestion should be discarded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.  For instance, let $G$ be any finite nonabelian group of odd order, and enumerate it in an order $\{e,g_1,g_2,\dots,g_n\}$ such that for each $k\leq n/2$, $g_{2k-1}=g_{2k}^{-1}$.  We can do this because for all $g\in G$ besides the identity, $g\neq g^{-1}$ (since $|G|$ is odd).  Then $g_1\dots g_n=e$, so $(g_1\dots g_n)^2=e$.

If every element of $G$ is its own inverse, then $G$ is automatically abelian.  Indeed, we have $g^2h^2=e=(gh)^2=ghgh$ for any $g,h\in G$, and multiplying on the left by $g^{-1}$ and on the right by $h^{-1}$, we get $gh=hg$.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying take $G$, a finitie nonabelian group of odd order, and arrange ${e,g_1,\dots,g_n} so that each element is next to its own inverse? That way when you multiply it all out you'll simply be squaring the identity element which is obviously still the identity?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!